# Appcrash with cURL

Tags: curl, libcurl, crash

What I'm trying with libcurl is send a GET request to a server and save the response. It works fine when i don't use CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and CURLOPT_WRITEFDATA, response goes to the standard stream and the program closes after a button press.

When i add my own function and a variable to save the response, however, there is and additional garbage character at the end of the response and the program crashes after a button press.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include "curl/curl.h"
#include "curl/easy.h"

#define FAIL 0
#define PASS 1

size_t curlWrite(void*, size_t, size_t, void*);

CURL        *curl;
const char  *baseURL = "XXXX";
const char  *authHeader = "Authorization: Token token=YYYY";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool cURLStatus = PASS;
    CURLcode res;

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, authHeader);
    char *response;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, baseURL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curlWrite);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, response);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(CURLE_OK != res) cURLStatus = FAIL;
    }
    else cURLStatus = FAIL;

    if(cURLStatus) printf("Response: %s", response);
    else           printf("Error: %s", curl_easy_strerror(res));

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    _getch();

    return 0;
}

static size_t curlWrite(void *src, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *dst)
{
    printf("Source: %s", src);
    memcpy(dst, src, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

This is the response i get, followed by an APPCRASH, using the code above:

> Source: {"current_bac":0,"time_until_sober":0}
>
> 0
>
> Response: {"current_bac":0,"time_until_sober":0}P

If i comment out the following lines (and a printf):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curlWrite);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, response);
```

I get this:

> {"current_bac":0,"time_until_sober":0}

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Man, looking at similar problems around i was sure i had to compile libcurl myself.

Actually, solution is to use:

```
char *response = (char *)malloc( sizeof(*response) * 100 );
```

Instead of:

```
char *response;
```